# CheckBox content from two fields of a custom Object in XAML/WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, data-binding

In the below code:
`RectifiedString` is property of a class say '`X`'.
i.e  `List<StringDetails> RectifiedString { get; set; }`.
`StringDetails` has fields: `InitialString`, `FinalString`, `isSelected`. I want to have a checklistListBox with the list of rectified strings. However, the content of the CheckBox is a string which is a combination of `InitialString` &  `FinalString`.I am trying to get something like the first box, but I am getting  the second box.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="6"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding RectifiedString}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox>
                <CheckBox.Content>
                   <StackPanel>
                       <Label Content="Initial String"/>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding InitialString}"/>
                       <Label Content="Final String"/>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding FinalString}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
                </CheckBox.Content>
              </CheckBox>   
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Note :

- I have taken care of the scope of Class X.
- When I replace the Binding on textblocks with static strings, they work fine except that it has additional padding around the textblock.
- In the image, there is a small correction. I am not shown the Initial String in any of the three items in the list. I am shown the correct final string though. Basically, it is only binding one textblock only - the final string in this case.
- Another problem that I was facing: I am unable to bind the `isChecked` Property of the CheckBox with the `isSelected` property of `RectifiedString`. It is showing me errors if I add `isChecked="{Binding isSelected}"`  inside the `<CheckBox>` 
  [image]

Comment: Can you share your backend code for more detailed view?

Comment: Which part of the backend info do you need ? Actually, I am trying to populate this UI part first. Based on this check boxes the user selects in the UI, I was planning to implement the corresponding backend .I have added the relevant backend info though. These three entries in the list(Rectified String) I have shown are hardcoded for the purpose of verification. It is hardcoded in the class X constructor

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and it works on my pc. If i'm not wrong you said you had a class like:

```
public class StringDetails
{
    public string InitialString
    { get; set; }
    public string FinalString
    { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say you have your list initialized like

```
RectifiedString = new List<StringDetails>() {new StringDetails { InitialString = "AAA", FinalString= "BBB" }, new StringDetails { InitialString = "BBB", FinalString = "AAA" } };
```

You should check your "stringDetails" names because it works.

You could post your codebehind/MVVM code so we can take a look there.

Comment: Yes, I have a class like this and have initialized RectifiedString in the same way as you have done. Except that I have one more field as i had mentioned in the post - the isSelected property. Does it work for you with the same XAML that I posted here ? Actually, there is nothing in my code behind. Backing this XAML is a ViewModel which is too large to provide here.

Comment: Yep, I used that XAML. Thibk about one thing... if your list is populated (check it) and you can see 3 checkboxes on your screen you are really binding it. If you get to this point and you can’t see the data it could be because your names aren’t right (finalString,Finalstring etc etc) . It’s hard to tell without your code, try to give us as much as you could of the way you populate, your classes...

Comment: Yeah, you are right - this is so frustrating man. I had used `Intial String` instead of `Initial String`. Thanks Anyways

Comment: Also, Could you take a look at the binding of the isSelected? as I mentioned in the point 4 of my Note.

Comment: Post your xaml code so I can take a look... but check you wrote it “IsChecked” and not “isChecked” :P